# DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit NOT found

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

Is it possible to implement the same discussed in http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q337799.aspx using DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit?

I found most of the properties and events are
missing for RepositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit
which are present in SearchLookUpEdit

I would like to use the _TextChanged event in order to bind
RepositoryItemSearchLookUpEdit data source on
the fly.

Comment: can't you ask directly devexpress support?

Answer (score 0):

can you provide an exemple of properties ? And check if there is a different access to the property, for example, the property DataSource in the lookupEdit and the RepositoryItemLookupEdit :

LookupEdit :

```
myLookup.Properties.DataSource
```

RepositoryItemLookupEdit :

```
myRiLookupEdit.DataSource
```